# loading js files dynamically via another js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there anyway to load other JS files from within a single JS file. I would like to point my individual pages "ITS" js file and that js file would load jquery, other js files.

I know i can just pop all these into the html  i.e.

I was thinking of separations of concerns so i was wondering if anything exists already without me reinventing the wheel....

That i would just need  to edit home.js to change what other js (jquery etc) are loaded for home.htm ... home.htm would just point to home.js

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can take a look at [dynamic script loading](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html). Here's an excerpt from the article:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'helper.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 3):

**For external domain JS link**

```
var loadJs = function(jsPath) { 
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src', jsPath);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
};
loadJs('http://other.com/other.js');
```

**For same domain JS link (Using jQuery)**

```
var getScript = function(jsPath, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType:'script',
        async:false,
        cache:true,
        url:jsPath,
        success:function(response) {
            if (callback && typeof callback == 'function') callback();
        }
    });
};
getScript('js/other.js', function() { functionFromOther(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Darin's solution, except it doesn't make any variables.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src = "helper.js";
```

Comment: Or you could just wrap the more readable solution in `(function() {...})();`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you take a look at labJS. It's a library made specifically to load Javascript. As they say..."The core purpose of LABjs is to be an all-purpose, on-demand JavaScript loader, capable of loading any JavaScript resource, from any location, into any page, at any time."

See [the labJS home page](http://labjs.com/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Google offers centrally hosted versions of the major javascript libraries like jQuery. They can be dynamically loaded using the google loader.

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/