# loading js file within js

Tags: javascript

i have code like this: [loading js files dynamically via another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618351/loading-js-files-dynamically-via-another-js-file) but it fails to recognize the object within.

ie. content of cCB.js

```
cCB = {

    map: {},
    ...
}
```

etc.

using:

```
function jsinclude(file) {
    var script  = document.createElement('script');
    script.src  = file;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.defer = false;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script);
}
```

with the calling code:

```
jsinclude('/js/cCB.js');
```

produces in  my html head

```
<script src="/js/cCB.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but at the first call to a var within that object:

```
cCB.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
```

i get error:

```
referenceError: can't find variable cCB
```

========
have I missed something silly here? I have searched already (hence the link) but have no answer

Comment: i have just had a thought that maybe the file is loaded in sync so maybe the var is referred to before the file is loaded?

Comment: add an alert() to the file that you load so that you can verify that it gets loaded

Comment: as the article you refer to and yankee suggests, you should check to see that the js file is loaded first. I don't know the rest of your code, but the dynamically-loaded js file is the last element in the head tag, so it'll be loaded after any other script file in the head element. Unless you run the `cCB.map = new google.maps.Map...` code at body.onload time or sometime that's guaranteed to be after the dynamically-loaded js file's script tag has been run, you'll see that error.

Comment: my fears are confirmed. if I put a breakpoint in after the file load and before the reference, wait a few seconds then continue, hey presto it sees the var: asynchronous loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). In your case, you could define a cCB module inside file /js/cCB.js with:

```
define({
    map: {},
    ...
});
```

And then use it as:

```
require([ "cCB" ], function (cCB) {
    // Module cCB loaded and accessible through the cCB argument
    cCB.map = ...
});
```

Comment: this sort-of worked but due to the complex nature of how i have set up my site i would have had to do a rewrite to accommodate it. if no better solutions i will tick this

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [LABjs](http://labjs.com/). It is designed for loading scripts dynamically, and has the option of preserving a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to do with waiting for the DOM to be ready?  I.e., the script file needs to fully load?  I think I recall seeing this problem before.  You might try using a timer to test if the variable exists, and keep running the timer until it does, at which point you clear the timer.

```
var timer;

function checkVar() {
    if(typeof cCB == "undefined") timer = setTimeout('checkVar()', 10);
    else clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Caveat: haven't tested this.

Comment: couldn't get this to work, sorry, would have been best solution for me too