# How to properly link external JS resources into a JS file?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a dashboard that shows different graphs in my web application. I got this code snippets and edited as needed. I realized that my web application is getting bigger. Therefore, I'd decided to create a separate javascript files for each graphs. Initially, I had all my  tag at the bottom of my html page which works just fine. I also have external resources such as;

```
<!-- External Resources -->          
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>

<!-- Functions -->
<script>
    // more codes here. But these codes will go to new .js file
</script>
```

Question, on my new .js file, how do I link all these external resources correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean dynamic loading of Javascript? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618351/loading-js-files-dynamically-via-another-js-file

Comment: Hi. So when I transfer all my JS codes from my html file to a new JS files, I cannot properly link the external resources anymore because when they were in the html page, they were in <script src="..."></script> and it was easy to load them up. When I transfer them to .js file, I cannot load the urls anymore from the script tag. Please advise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IvanKuckir That's wrong. Javascript code is executed in the same order as defined in HTML page. Thus, if you have three script-elements with the first and last referring to external file and the second injecting code inline the first referenced file is executed prior to the inline code, which is executed prior to the last referenced file.

Comment: @Marvin As an advise, please check out the link I've posted above - this question tends to be a duplicate of that one ... you can't use script-tag in JS file, but have to add elements to your DOM dynamically using Javascript. And since that's going to work asynchronously you require to handle synchronization of your code with the files loaded there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loading js files dynamically via another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618351/loading-js-files-dynamically-via-another-js-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the "external resources" scope their code, so you can't access it in the global scope, you will be able to access everything in a JS file, just as you would within a script tag, in the document.

If your javascript code is working between `<script>` tags, it will also work when you move it into a file, and replace the `<script>` tags with something like this:

`<script src="/code.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. When I add the <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"> in the .js file, it doesn't recognize the <script> tag anymore. In my inspect element, I get an error of "unexpected token <".

Comment: Yes, that will work, as long as you place it before your own code, so you can access it

Comment: @Marvin You can't put `<script>`-tags in a JS file and expect them to work. Those tags are HTML-way of embedding something non-HTML in an HTML document. A JS-file isn't HTML at all and thus gets parsed by the same part of browser that's instructed to parse what is between those <script>-tags ... Thus, if you want to load JS from another JS file this answer is misleading.

Comment: I just realised that he tried to add the script tag inside the JS file itself. That is indeed not where to place it. They should be placed inside the HTML file, only.

Comment: But that's why this answer isn't actually matching the question for somewhat explicitly asking for "how to link external Javascript in a Javascript file", which I think means to load Javascript dynamically using Javascript code. Nonetheless, if the thread linked in my comment on question doesn't satisfy returning to HTML might be preferrable option.

Comment: I don't think he's talking about dynamically loading them, but loading multiple scripts in a page, correctly. However, the question is not clear at all.

Comment: Hi. I fixed the problem. So I was loading my .js files before I load my external resources. The DOM reads my .js files before it reads the external resources. It breaks from there because I keep calling AmCharts on my .js files but It doesn't know what it is. Sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are included at the beginning of your HTML as you have shown here, you should be fine.